# Embedding yammer feed skipping OAuth, using access token only

Tags: javascript, oauth, yammer

I have successfully authenticated user and I stored its access token in the database. I use it to call some Rest API from the server side. When user logs out, yammer forces logging in again to access embedded feeds.
Is it possible to authenticate (or impersonate) user automatically, using only its token via JavaScript to access embedded feeds?
I'm not going to call Rest API as described [here](https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk), I just need to embed feed skipping yammer login page, using access token only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved the OAUTH token of a user in your database then you can re-use that token to authenticate against Yammer even if the user has logged out of Yammer and logged back in, however I would advise against storing user OAUTH tokens because they do not expire.

Comment: The Yammer developer documentation at http://developer.yammer.com goes into great detail about how you can use an OAUTH token to authenticate against Yammer. Sample code for how you could do this with Ruby is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564330/yammers-rest-api-to-share-a-post/25576327#25576327. I can't explain how you would do it with JavaScript.